# for of loop iteration and elisions

Tags: javascript

What are the algorithmic steps that define for-of iteration includes elisions?

```
const a = [1, , 2];
for(b of a) console.log(b);
```

What I am seeing in the Brave is:

```
1
undefined
2
```

What explains this result?

Comment: The two commas in your array with no value in-between cause that

Comment: You have 3 "things" in your array, one of them is not set to anything (aka, undefined). What exactly are you asking?

Comment: No, DBS, I do not have three "things" in my array. I have two.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithmic steps are defined in the language specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-%25arrayiteratorprototype%25.next) (`%ArrayIteratorPrototype%.next`).

When used with an array, `for...of` uses the iterator present on the `Symbol.iterator` property of `Array.prototype`.

This iterator starts at index zero and increments one at a time. If the array does not have a property at that a given index, then it returns `undefined` for that index.

Array elisions are not a quirk of the language, but a feature: JavaScript arrays may be [sparse](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/9480/sparse-array). Some other languages support sparse arrays too.

Note that the enumeration methods that do not use iterators (eg. `forEach`, `map` and `reduce`) behave differently with sparse arrays: they ignore the elisions completely.

Comment: +1. While your explanation could have been expounded upon with more detail, it was not incorrect. I upvoted. Other answers and comments, unfortunately, were mistaken. Perhaps they mistook yours as false and downvoted (?).  https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset is hard. Is it `iterationKind` or `iteratorKind`?

Answer (score -1):

### The Reason

Very typical that JavaScript does this - every other language would just throw a Syntax Error ^^

The missing element between the two commas in your code

`const a = [1, , 2];`

are interpreted as a `undefined` JavaScript object.